# Adaptando aplicación .NET Core con Identity a autentificación B2C

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity

Veréis, he implementado toda mi aplicación con Identity he creado un sistema de usuarios y roles para la implementación de esta. Por petición del cliente he tenido que cambiar el sistema de logueo a una autentificacion B2C como la que aparece a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El logueo se realiza correctamente, accedo a la aplicación y consigo obtener el token con el que acceder a mis controladores. La cosa es que yo antes utilizando identity tenía una tabla usuarios con los siguientes atributos:

Usuarios:
[Id],[UserName],[NormalizedUserName],[Email],[NormalizedEmail],[EmailConfirmed],[PasswordHash],[SecurityStamp],[ConcurrencyStamp] ,[PhoneNumber],[PhoneNumberConfirmed],[TwoFactorEnabled],[LockoutEnd],[LockoutEnabled],[AccessFailedCount],[Version],[DeletionDate],[DeleteUserId],[IsDeleted],[CreatorUserId]
,[CreationDate],[LastModificationDate],[LastModificationUserId],[Nombre],[Apellidos],[Bloqueado],[IdiomaPorDefectoId],[EmpresaPorDefectoId],[CustomerId]

Y claro con este tipo de autentificación, pierdo parte de la información que recolectaba anteriormente. ¿Alguien sabe como hacer cohexistir estas dos opciones o como integrarlas juntas?

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Me tocó hacer algo parecido al escenario que plantes y lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

*En esta explicación me referiré a los usuarios existentes en Identity como Usuarios locales*

- Agregué una tabla en en la base de datos que relaciona el ID de usuario de B2C con su correspondiente ID de usuario local.
- Una vez que el login tiene exito, obtengo del Token el ID del usuario de B2C para encontrar el ID del usuario local en la tabla nueva.

Con este enfoque logré mantener toda la lógica existente de administración de roles / usuarios y toda la información relacionada como por ejemplo, los logs que registran la actividad de cada usuario en el sistema.

También fue necesario crear mecanismos para mantener sincronizados los usuarios locales con B2C.

Espero que encuentres algo de inspiración con este aporte.